# exporting .mov vr to multiple still frames

Tags: software, file-formats, software-recommendation, quicktime, formats

Ive got a quicktime VR in .mov format i need to strip the all still frames (in total there are 250) out of it and have them in as individual images, preferably pngs or jpegs.

I was looking at using quicktime pro for this, is that the right software to do it ? Would you suggest trying another method ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you do not have access to the original files before they were made into a Quicktime VR? It seems you are asking to reverse engineer what Quicktime created, were these converted to make panoramic shots?

Comment: hi, the vr is actualy of a 3d model that i rendered in artlantis, unfortunatly they only let you export the quicktime file, not invidual images. Although when rendering the process it goes though is to render 250 seperate images and then combine them together in a quicktime file.

Comment: Calling all "artlantis" experts, this has your name on it. :>

Comment: @sam Do you have any other software on your computer? (eg. Adobe After Effects)

Comment: no, just artlantis studio & imovie

Comment: I have tried using Quicktime Player 7 Pro for just this task and have had no luck exporting a image series from the Quicktime VR .mov file. My output is a single frame over and over... In my case, the input file an Equirectangular image created by processing 6 images (360deg). I hope to convert this to an image series so I can use "Reel" viewer. Reel viewer will display an image sequence, hence the need to convert the .mov to an image sequence. As an alternative, is there a way to go from Equirectangular directly to image sequence?

Comment: As @user4751 when I do this I just get the key frame once (or repeatedly if I specify a framerate). Has anyone been able to confirm this method or can you advise what else we need to do?

Comment: Revisiting this as hadn't cracked it before and got one step further following https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7662805 which has got me as far as getting 97 individual frames out but haven't been able to recombine these to a newer supported format... yet... Has anyone got a working answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using [Quicktime Player 7](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL923) you can export any movie file as an Image Sequence**

1. **Open your .mov** file using Quicktime 7
2. **File > Export**
3. In the Export dropdown select **Movie to Image Sequence**
   [image: Export dialogue box]
4. Open the options and set the **export format** (eg JPEG or PNG)
   [image: Image Sequence options]
5. If you want just the current frame leave the **frames per second** blank. Otherwise, enter hte videos frame rate and you will export ALL the frames.

Comment: great, thats it qt pro right ?

Comment: @sam I'm going to say yes. The computer I have it installed on also has Final Cut studio installed which comes with a Pro licence, so I have no way to test if the export to image sequence option is in the normal version

Comment: i think it is, checking the standard version almost all options are greyed out with "pro" written next to them

Answer (score 0):

**You can also use [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/) which is FREE!** (Its also good for files which arent compatible with QT)

1. Open the movie file with Mpeg Streamclip
2. Choose **File –> Export to other Formats**.
3. In the export options window: go to the Format drop-down menu and choose **Image Sequence**.
4. Click **Options** and choose the image format. (Leave Frame per Seconds at 'best'), click OK.
5. In 'Frame Size', choose 'unscaled' to leave the image at its original size
6. Click OK to export

Comment: thanks for providing a free alternative. It keeps giving me an error saying the movie is too long, as a vr it dosnt really have a length, but when i click on "get info" it says the duration is 25 seconds which dosnt seem particularly long. Any idea why it might be saying its too long ?

Comment: hmm not sure. cant test it myself as I dont have any vrs. But maybe you could try setting an in and out point? (using the I & O keys)